# How do pets work?

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

Now that the game has been released, those with the Deluxe Edition of The Old Republic get a Training Droid pet and those with the Collector's Edition additionally get a Mouse Droid.  How do these pets work?  In particular, I'm wondering:

1. Is there a limit to the number of pets you can have?
2. Can they be upgraded or leveled up?
3. Are there others besides the Training Droid that join in combat?

I'm also assuming they're more like items and don't have "feelings" like companions; do correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're correct in your assumption that they do not share the "feelings" or affection statistics.

1. There is a limit to one Cartel Pack or Gree Reputation "spaceship pet" and one non-spaceship (creature, droid) pet out at a time, in addition to your active companion.  There is no effective limit on how many you can own.
2. They cannot be levelled or upgraded at this time.
3. The training droid is an item rather than a pet, and does not join in combat but simply can be used to place an effect around your target.  There are no pets that provide combat damage or anything outside of audio/visuals at this time, and doubt they will add such features since our companions fill this role.

These items are mostly for visual appeal and to add to the game world, possibly for role-play elements as well.

Hopefully this answers your questions Matthew , **may the force be with you....**

Comment: If your ever on Grand Master Zym server shoot me a message "Kiraji" if you need anything =)